# Visual Studio cannot find some C libraries, such as stropts.h

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I'm attempting to compile a sample c file that was given to me, but unfortunately, it's missing several libraries as some of the include files cannot find them. Namely: stropts.h, netdb.h, sys/socket.h, sys/ioctl.h, netinet/in.h, pthread.h, and unistd.h.

I've researched where I could fix these problems, but surprisingly there have been little to no results on this problem strangely. The Visual Studio command prompt isn't able to compile it until I can find these libraries. Anything I need to download/ link to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried e.g. `#include <cstropt>`? A lot of the C libraries got renamed in (IIRC) C99.

Comment: @DragoonWraith I think `cstropt` is for C++ not for C.

Comment: Given the headers you named I suspect the code was for Unix. Is that right ?

Comment: @cnicutar: You know, you're probably right. Derp.

Comment: Yes, that's true. The code was created in linux, so that's likely unix-related libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those header files are not part of standard C or C++.  Do not attempt to download the headers from other sources; even if you can get them to compile, they won't link properly since you don't have the implementations of the functions declared therein in a static library or DLL.

The simple fact of the matter is that the code you're trying to compile was written for Unix/Unix-like systems and it's not portable to Windows.  You'll need to either significantly rewrite the code to use the equivalent Windows functionality or a 3rd-party platform-independent library (e.g. Winsock or Boost sockets for sockets), compile it on a Unix system (you could use a virtual machine if you want), or use a Unix compatibility layer such as Cygwin.

Comment: Alright. Thanks guys. That makes sense since the code was created on a Linux station from someone else.